# using find to check, if I have underscores in a string

Tags: c++, find

im heading several problems in my program, but here is one of them.
I want my code to check if there are two or more underscores in one string next to each other, 
example>

```
lol__lol, lol___lol, etc...
```

should I do it using while? here is my actual code, which works only for checking when I put underscores like this>

```
_lol_
```

so first and last characters are _ and they cant, so it works, because I get output "Chyba - error"

```
std::string::size_type n;
std::string const ss = slovo;

n  = ss.find('_');

// kontrola podtrznika
if ((ss[0] >= 'A' && ss[0] <= 'Z') && ss[1] == '_')
{
    cout << "chyba" << endl;
}

if ( !ss.empty() && ss[0] == '_' && ss[ss.length() - 1] == '_' )
{
    cout << "chyba" << endl;
}

if ( ss.length() > 3 && ss.find( "__", 1, ss.length() - 2 ) != std::string::npos )
{
    cout << "chyba" << endl;
}

if (n == std::string::npos)
{
    string s = transform(slovo);
    cout << s << endl;
}
else
{
    string s = untransform(slovo);
    cout << s << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code seems massively overcomplicated, unless you were misleading in your requirements.

Surely the following is sufficient:

```
if (slovo.find("__") != slovo.npos) {
   // ...
}
```

Comment: and what if i type more than two underscores?

Comment: @feri what about it? If it has more than two consecutive underscores, it also has two. So this test works.

Comment: @feri: The string `__` is found in the string `___`.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear whether you are going to determine that a string contains within it two or more underscores as for example

"A__B"

or you are going to check whether there is at least two adjacent underscores as for example

`"__A"` or `"A__"`

For these two cases two different approaches should be used.

In the second case you simply can use the following call

```
ss.find( "__" );
```

In the first case the task is more difficult. At first you should find the first character that is not underscore. Then you need to find the last character that is not underscore and after that apply function find as

```
ss.find( "__", start_position, length_of_substring );
```